# ias is undefined while adding event

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I have this in my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ias = jQuery.ias({
        container : ".category-products",
        item : "#products-list",
        next : "a.next",
        pagination : '.pages',
        loader : '<img src="/skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/ajax-loader-tr.gif" alt="Loading...">',
        triggerPageThreshold : 9999
    });
    ias.on('loaded', function (items) { //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        console.log('random');
    })
});
```

This is in my head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.digitalcinema.com.au/skin/frontend/enterprise/helloshopper/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/auto-load/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
```

On scroll, new items are loading, but `ias.on('loaded', function (items)` is throwing error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the actual error is `ias` is undefined on that line. Even I tried to change that to `load`, but still the same error.

Comment: ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());       
ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 3}));  add this two line before on loaded method

Comment: Because `ias` is undefined, it now shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extension' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [onLoadItems](https://github.com/fieg/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll#onloaditems) for new items loaded, as::

```
jQuery.ias({
    container : ".category-products",
    item : "#products-list",
    next : "a.next",
    pagination : '.pages',
    loader : '<img src=".." alt="Loading...">',
    triggerPageThreshold : 9999,
    onLoadItems: function( items ) {
        console.log('item loaded');
    }
});
```